# Timestamp conversion is off by an hour

Tags: python, django, datetime, time

I'm trying to parse a twitter feed in django, and I'm having a strange problem converting the published time:

I've got the time from the feed into a full 9-tuple correctly:

```
>> print tweet_time
time.struct_time(tm_year=2009, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=17, tm_hour=14, tm_min=35, tm_sec=28, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=168, tm_isdst=0)
```

But when I call this:

```
tweet_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(tweet_time))
```

I end up with the a time 1 hour ahead:

```
>> print tweet_time
2009-06-17 15:35:28
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try flipping the isdst (is daylight savings flag) to a -1 and see if that fixes it. -1 tells it to use (guess) the local daylight savings setting and roll with that.

Comment: Your suggestion was right, though some hint of how to do that would've been helpful. The working code is this:

tweet_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(tweet_time[0:8] + (-1,)))

All that trouble for a bad DST flag. Grr.

Comment: This reminds that you should use UTC internally and convert it to local time for output only (like display). Pytz to the rescue.

Comment: @zgoda would love to see a clean example of how to do that.